# Embedding Label to other websites in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, embed

I am working on a website & it required to show a counter on home page.So I used an asp label as a counter that counts & display the DB records  (i.e. 180000).It is working perfectly alright.

Now problem is that.I want to make it embed able
 I want to embed that label to other websites.

```
e.g : <EMBED SRC="http://www.XXXX.com/graphics/sounds/18.mid" HEIGHT=60 WIDTH=144>
```

It should be dynamic (Counter Changes on home page should reflect where this counter has been embedded i.e. on blogs or on forums ) .

How can I do this?

Also what would be the best approach,a simple embed code, a iframe  or through Java Script?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you have some generic html, that when it is embedded into someone else's site, it updates a counter on your central server that is then used to update a label on your home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.  Without more information, it's hard to recommend an exact method.  If all you want to do is display a number in html, then you can simply create an aspx page that writes the number and then let people iframe to it.

If you want to get more dynamic, you can create a [generic ashx handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx), or set up a [web service](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-and-call-a-simple-web-service-in-aspnet) that displays that information for you.